# JavaScript functions in PHP echo statement

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, echo

I am trying to use javascript functions in a php echo statement. The showme and onclick function are being used and values must be passed in the showme function.

The code below is not working.

```
 echo"
  <ul>
  <li><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='showme('Test','','10.70725','-61.55391','','Tester');' >$id</a></li>
</ul>
  ";
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: That's a horrible way to output HTML and use JavaScript. Just sayin'. Look into *views* and *unobtrusive event handling*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo"
  <ul>
  <li><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick=\"showme('Test','','10.70725','-61.55391','','Tester');\" >$id</a></li>
</ul>
  ";
```

Comment: it helps the OP if there's an explanation of how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

So don't echo so much using PHP simply make it like this, and also add the `"` quotes around your `showme()`

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showme('Test','','10.70725','-61.55391','','Tester');"><?php echo $id; ?></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: As you said you are running this in a while loop you can do it like this

I assume that you are extracting the data from the database

```
<?php
  while($blah = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_blah)) {
?>
<!--HTML Part Goes Here-->
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showme('Test','','10.70725','-61.55391','','Tester');"><?php echo $blah['id']; ?></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Cant use it like this because I am running this echo statement within a PHP while loop. Therefore I need it in the PHP code as and echo statement? How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This will do, add `\" \"` on your echo :

```
echo"
  <ul>
  <li><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick=\"showme('Test','','10.70725','-61.55391','','Tester');\" >$id</a>          </li>
 </ul>
  ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please escape your double quote.

```
 echo "
  <ul>
  <li><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"showme('Test','','10.70725','-61.55391','','Tester');\" >$id</a></li>
</ul>
  ";
```

Answer (score 0):

To make things a lot simpler to read, try exiting your PHP to display your HTML (instead of using `echo` to display it):

```
?>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showme('Test','','10.70725','-61.55391','','Tester');" ><?=$id;?></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<?php
```

This will fix the quote-escaping issue in your original code, and make it easier to read.

Comment: @Mr.Alien And your reasoning for this, beyond not sanitizing the output (which a regular `<?php echo $id; ?>` doesn't help with either)?

Comment: I've never came accross that thing, I guess that's not a standard way to use it..

Comment: @Mr.Alien I've been a PHP-dev for over 6 years; that's the most common way I've ever seen it in professional code, open-source code, books, etc.

Comment: it's probably worth noting that `<?=` will not work if `short open tag` is not enabled. usually it isn't.

Comment: @tradyblix (before version 5.4; now, `<?=` is allowed by default *without* `short_open_tag`)

Comment: @newfurniturey got to learn a new thing but we can't guess he is using the latest so better stick with standards..

Answer (score 0):

Check the Escape Characters/ Escape Sequences
[Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php ]

```
<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick=\"showme('Test','','10.70725','-61.55391','','Tester');\">$id</a></li>
```

To use double quotes use the escape character \" which results in -> "

As suggested in other answers, simple echo out the $id instead of the whole html snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
echo " ...
onclick="showme('Test','','10.70725','-61.55391','','Tester');"><?php echo $id; ?></a>
...";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using quotes in html  instead of apostrophes:

```
$result =<<<TSTSTR
<ul>
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);' onclick='showme('Test','','10.70725','-61.55391','','Tester');'">$id</a>
</li>
</ul>
TSTSTR;

echo $result;
```